# Can I use two column on EXCLUDE USING gist?

Tags: postgresql

I am using EXCLUDE USING gist to block users to visit the same place twice unless 6 months have pass, but with my code it blocks user of going ANYWHERE unless 6 months have pass

```
CREATE SCHEMA code

CREATE TABLE code.place ( 
   pk_place_id VARCHAR(8), 
   place_name VARCHAR (50),
   CONSTRAINT pk_place_id PRIMARY KEY (pk_place_id)
);


CREATE TABLE code.user ( 
   pk_user_id VARCHAR(3), 
   user_name VARCHAR (50),
   CONSTRAINT pk_user_id PRIMARY KEY (pk_user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE code.visit ( 
   pk_user_id VARCHAR(3), 
   pk_place_id VARCHAR(8),
   data DATE,
   CONSTRAINT pk_user_id FOREIGN KEY (pk_user_id) REFERENCES code.user,
   CONSTRAINT pk_place_id FOREIGN KEY (pk_place_id) REFERENCES code.place,
        EXCLUDE USING gist (pk_user_id WITH =, daterange(data, (data + interval '6 months')::date) WITH &&)
);
```

Comment: Just add `pk_place_id WITH =` to the constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thanks Laurenz Albe and Miles Elam for the help.
Here is the answer:

Yes you can add as many columns as you like to the table.

Here is one with just two column

```
EXCLUDE USING gist (user WITH =, data WITH &&)
```

Here is one with just three column

```
EXCLUDE USING gist (user WITH =, place WITH =, data WITH &&)
```

To summarize, just add the name of the column you like and then type **WITH =,**